# How to integrate AngularJs with Sails.js

Tags: angularjs, api, controller, sails.js, backend

I am creating a sails.js app. The front end was developed independently in AngularJS. I am confused as to how AngularJS should be integrated with sails.js. Should I be keeping the front and backend separately and keep firing the backend API's within the angular controller, or is there a better way of doing it?